# pandas how to count number of entries by id in a selected daterange

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a relatively big data frame (~10mln rows). It has an `id` and `DateTimeIndex`. I have to count a number of entries with a certain `id` for each row for a period of time (last week\month\year). I've created my own function using `relativedelta` and storing dates in a separate dictionary `{id: [dates]}`, but it works extremely slow. How should I do it fast and properly?

P.S.: I've heard about `pandas.rolling()` but I can't figure out how to use it correctly.

P.P.S.: my function:

```
def isinrange(date, listdate, delta):
    date,listdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,format),datetime.datetime.strptime(listdate,format)
    return date-delta<=listdate
```

main code, contains tons of unnecessary operations:

```
dictionary = dict() #structure {id: [dates]}
for row in df.itertuples():#filling a dictionary
    if row.id in dictionary:
        dictionary[row.id].append(row.DateTimeIndex)
    else:
        dictionary[row.id] = [row.DateTimeIndex,]

week,month,year = relativedelta(days =7),relativedelta(months = 1),relativedelta(years = 1)#relative delta init

for row, i in zip(df.itertuples(),range(df.shape[0])):#iterating over dataframe
    cnt1=cnt2=cnt3=0 #weekly,monthly, yearly - for each row
    for date in dictionary[row.id]:#for each date with an id from row
        index_date=row.DateTimeIndex 
        if date<=index_date: #if date from dictionary is lesser than from a row 
            if isinrange(index_date,date,year):
                cnt1+=1
            if isinrange(index_date,date,month):
                cnt2+=1
            if isinrange(index_date,date,week):
                cnt3+=1
    df.loc[[i,36],'Weekly'] = cnt1 #add values to a data frame
    df.loc[[i,37],'Monthly'] = cnt2
    df.loc[[i,38],'Yearly']=cnt3
```

Sample:

```
id  date
1   2015-05-19
1   2015-05-22
2   2018-02-21
2   2018-02-23
2   2018-02-27
```

Expected result:

```
id  date    last_week
1   2015-05-19  0
1   2015-05-22  1
2   2018-02-21  0
2   2018-02-23  1
2   2018-02-27  2
```

Comment: Please define "last week", e.g. does this mean last 7 days of month?

Comment: Can you also add the function you've written?

Answer (score 0):

```
year_range = ["2018"]
month_range = ["06"]
day_range = [str(x) for x in range(18, 25)]
date_range = [year_range, month_range, day_range]

# df = your dataframe
your_result = df[df.date.apply(lambda x: sum([x.split("-")[i] in date_range[i] for i in range(3)]) == 3)].groupby("id").size().reset_index(name="counts")
print(your_result[:5])
```

I'm not sure I understood correctly but is it something like this you're looking for?
Took ~15s with a 10 million rows "test" dataframe

```
   id  counts
0   0  454063
1   1  454956
2   2  454746
3   3  455317
4   4  454312
Wall time: 14.5 s
```

The "test" dataframe:

```
   id        date
0   4  2018-06-06
1   2  2018-06-18
2   4  2018-06-06
3   3  2018-06-18
4   5  2018-06-06
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not that. I want to iterate through a df, subtract week\month\year from each datetime and count number of entries with id of a row and within week\month\year

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd                                                                               
src = "path/data.csv"                                                        
df = pd.read_csv(src, sep=",")                                                                    
print df                                                                                          
#    id        date                                                                               
# 0   1  2015-05-19                                                                               
# 1   1  2015-05-22                                                                               
# 2   2  2018-02-21                                                                               
# 3   2  2018-02-23                                                                               
# 4   2  2018-02-27                                                                               

# Convert date column to a datetime                                                               
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])                                                           

# Retrieve rows in the date range                                                                 

date_ini = '2015-05-18'                                                                           
date_end = '2016-05-18'                                                                           

filtered_rows = df.loc[(df['date'] > date_ini) & (df['date'] <= date_end)]                        
print filtered_rows                                                                               
#    id       date                                                                                
# 0   1 2015-05-19                                                                                
# 1   1 2015-05-22                                                                                

# Group rows by id                                                                                
grouped_by_id = filtered_rows.groupby(['id']).agg(['count'])                                      
print  grouped_by_id                                                                              
#    count                                                                                        
# id                                                                                              
# 1      2
```

Comment: Thanks, that`s almost what I wanted. The only thing is that I have to iterate through dataframe, take date_init from each row.date and count number of entries within week\month\year. Using loc helped me to iterate in around 15 minutes. Don't you know how to do it quicker?